# Drawing semitransparent arrows in svg

Tags: reactjs, svg

I have an arrow React component, which draws an arrow over the board with given code. The problem is when I want to draw a semitransparent arrow, it looks ugly, as the area of shapes coalision becomes darker.

How I can fix it considering that its important to make arrow point exact on the coords given from props?

```
const Arrow = ({ from, to, customArrowColor }) => (
  <Fragment>
    <defs>
      <marker
        id="arrowhead"
        markerWidth="2"
        markerHeight="2.5"
        refX="1.25"
        refY="1.25"
        orient="auto"
      >
        <polygon
          points="0 0, 2 1.25, 0 2.5"
          style={{ fill: "rgba(28, 195, 42, 0.35)" }}
        />
      </marker>
    </defs>
    <line
      x1={from.x}
      y1={from.y}
      x2={to.x}
      y2={to.y}
      style={{
        stroke: "rgba(28, 195, 42, 0.35)",
      }}
      markerEnd="url(#arrowhead)"
    />
  </Fragment>
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use opaque colors and change your `<line>` elements opacity instead:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml, %3Csvg viewBox='0 0 10 9' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' %3E%3Cpath d='M0 0 L10 0 L10 9' stroke-width='1' fill='none' stroke='%23eee' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <marker id="arrowhead" markerWidth="2" markerHeight="2.5" refX="1.25" refY="1.25" orient="auto">
    <polygon points="0 0, 2 1.25, 0 2.5" fill="rgba(28, 195, 42, 1)"  />
  </marker>
    <line x1="0" y1="50" x2="50" y2="50" opacity="0.5" stroke="rgba(28, 195, 42, 1)" stroke-width="5"  style="marker-end:url(#arrowhead)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: There was a second answer, idk who and why deleted the second answer, but the combination of both answers gave me the desired result.
Your solution fixes the opaque problem, but it makes my arrows a bit longer than I need, so I have to recalculate and reduce <line/> height a bit by myself  using geometry formulas